# Convert nested C loops into a single boost index?

Tags: c++, boost, cartesian-product

I'm slowly learning `boost` and I'm trying to find a simple way to convert the following C++ snippet:

```
for(int i=-n;i<n+1;i++) {
  for(int j=-n;j<n+1;j++) {
     for(int k=-n;k<n+1;k++) {
       cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << k << endl;
     }
  }
}
```

Into a single iterator that I can loop over. In my native language `python` (can I call it that?), this is a one-liner using `itertools`:

```
itrtools.product(range(-n,n+1),repeat=3)
```

A complete answer would provide a minimal working example and a link to the docs so I can RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each_product.html) in [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) that can do this at pre-process step.

> The BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT macro repeats a macro for each cartesian product of several seqs.

But I suppose that is not what you are looking for.

If a little reusable code is ok then you can use [Function Input Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html) in [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) to generate cartesian product of given range.

**Generator**

```
class product_generator
{
    public:
        typedef std::vector<int> result_type;

        product_generator (int lower, int upper, unsigned int repeat)
            : m_lower(lower), m_upper(upper)
        {  
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
            {  
                m_iters.push_back(m_lower);
            }
        };

        std::vector<int> operator() ()
        {  
            for(int& i : m_iters)
            {  
                if(++i >= m_upper)
                    i = m_lower;
                else
                    break;
            }

            std::vector<int> res;
            for(int i : m_iters)
                res.push_back(i);

            return res;
        };

    private:
        int m_lower;
        int m_upper;
        std::vector<int> m_iters;
};
```

Using this generator, you can do something like:

```
product_generator p(lower, upper, repeat);
auto bgn = boost::make_function_input_iterator(p, (double)0);
```

`bgn` is the single iterator that you can loop over to generate Cartesian product of the input sequence formed by input range.

A complete working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int lower = 1;
    int upper = 4;
    unsigned int repeat = 3;

    product_generator p(lower, upper, repeat);

    for(   
            auto bgn = boost::make_function_input_iterator(p, (double)0);
            bgn != boost::make_function_input_iterator(p, pow(upper-lower, repeat));
            ++bgn
       )
    {  
        for(int i : *bgn)
        {  
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```